# Classification of equilibrium configurations for particles subject to elastic force constrained on a circle

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator, equilibrium

I am interested in classifying all the possible equilibrium configurations for an arrangement of $l$ equal point particles $P_1, P_2, . . . , P_l$ $(l > 2)$ on a circle of radius $R$ and centre $O$. The costraint is smooth and the $P_i$ is attracted to $P_{i−1}, P_{i+1}$ with an elastic force ($P_0= P_l$).

I have chosen to use $l-1$ lagrangian coordinates $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{l-1}$ to get rid of the additional degree of freedom given by rotating the full system, basically choosing a corotating radial coordinate system locked to $P_0$. $\alpha_i$ is the angle between $OP_{i-1}$ and $OP_{i}$.
With these coordinates I write the potential energy of the system as
$$V=2kR^2\{\sum_{1}^{l-1}sin^2(\frac{\alpha_i}{2})+sin^2(\frac{2\pi-\sum_{1}^{l-1}\alpha_i}{2})\}$$
as the length of a chord between two rays with angle $\alpha$ is $d=2Rsin(\alpha/2)$ and each couple of adjacent particles contributes to the elastic potential energy by $1/2kd^2$.
In order to find the equilibrium position I evaluate all the configurations in which $\nabla V=0$. As $\frac{\partial V}{\partial \alpha_i}$ is $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial \alpha_i}=2kR^2\{ 
sin(\frac{\alpha_i}{2})cos(\frac{\alpha_i}{2})
-
sin(\frac{2\pi-\sum_{1}^{l-1}\alpha_i}{2})
cos(\frac{2\pi-\sum_{1}^{l-1}\alpha_i}{2})
\}$$ the following configurations are equilibrium ones:
\begin{cases}
\alpha_i=2\pi/l \text{     } \forall i\\
\alpha_0...\alpha_i=0,\alpha_{i+1}...\alpha_{j}=\pi,\alpha_{j+1}...\alpha_{l-1}=0\text{  for   }0\leq i\leq j \leq l-1
\end{cases}

I would like to understand a general methodology to classify the above equilibrium configurations, i.e. ascertain which ones are unstable and which ones are stable. The Hessian $H$ of $V$ around the equilibrium points is not always a positive definite matrix, as for $l=3$ and $l=4$ we have:
$$\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial^2 \alpha_j}=2kR^2\{
\frac{1}{2}(cos^2(\frac{\alpha_i}{2})-sin^2(\frac{\alpha_i}{2}))
+
\frac{1}{2}(cos^2(\frac{2\pi-\sum_{1}^{l-1}\alpha_i}{2})-sin^2(\frac{2\pi-\sum_{1}^{l-1}\alpha_i}{2}))\}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial\alpha_j\partial\alpha_k}=2kR^2\{
\frac{1}{2}(cos^2(\frac{2\pi-\sum_{1}^{l-1}\alpha_i}{2})-sin^2(\frac{2\pi-\sum_{1}^{l-1}\alpha_i}{2}))\}$$
where $j\neq k$.
Hence, for $l=3$, $H=2kR^2 cos(2\pi/3) \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1/2\\1/2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ which is negative definite and for $l=4$ $H=2kR^2 cos(\pi/2) \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1/2 &1/2\\1/2 & 1 & 1/2\\1/2 & 1/2 &1\end{bmatrix}=0$.
The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1/2\\1/2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ corresponding to the stable equilibrium configuration $\alpha_0, \alpha_1 =0$ is positive definite, but for $l=3$ and $\alpha_i=2\pi/l \forall i$  we have that $cos(2\pi/3) < 0$.

Is this methodology correct? I would not have expected $(2/3\pi,2/3\pi,2/3\pi,)$ and $(\pi/2,\pi/2,\pi/2,\pi/2)$ to be not stable. What happens for $l>4$?